# Empty innerText in UseEffect React Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, circletype

I am having trouble understanding how useEffect works. 
I have a piece of code below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, createRef } from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import LoadingPage from "../LoadingPage";
import Slideshow from "../SlideShow"
import CircleType from "circletype";

function Home() {
  const categories = ["advance beauty", "beauty", "special effects", "airbrush", "others"]
  const images = useState(
    [[
      "/images/elegant_sugar_skull4.jpg",
      "/images/elegant_sugar_skull3.jpg",
      "/images/elegant_sugar_skull1.jpg"
    ],
    [
      "/images/3looks1.jpg",
      "/images/3looks4.jpg",
      "/images/3looks5.jpg"
    ],
    [
      "/images/daemon_of_buddha1.jpg",
      "/images/daemon_of_buddha6.jpg",
      "/images/daemon_of_buddha7.jpg"
    ],
    [
      "/images/gangstar4.jpg",
      "/images/gangstar2.jpg",
      "/images/gangstar6.jpg"
    ],
    [
      "/images/sculpture1.jpg",
      "/images/sculpture6.jpg",
      "/images/henna1.jpg"
    ]]);

useEffect(() => {
        const slideshow = new Slideshow(document.querySelector('.slideshow'));
        const topText = document.querySelectorAll('.bottom');
        console.log(topText[0].innerText);
        topText.forEach(text=>{
          console.log(text.innerText)
          new CircleType(text).radius(384)
        })
  }, []); 

return (
<div className="slideshow">
        {categories.map((category, index) => (
            <div className="slide" key={index}>
            <div className="slide__number white-text">0{index + 1}</div>
              <div className="slide__img-wrap">
                <img className="slide__img" src={images[0][index][0]} onLoad={checkLoaded} alt="img" />
                <img className="slide__img2" src={images[0][index][1]} onLoad={checkLoaded} alt="img" />
                <img className="slide__img3"  src={images[0][index][2]} onLoad={checkLoaded} alt="img" />
                <div className="slide__img-reveal"></div>
              </div>
              {category.includes(" ") ?
              <div className="slide__title">
                <h1 className="white-text top">{category.split(" ")[0]}</h1>
                <h1 className="white-text bottom" ref={bottomText}>{category.split(" ")[1]}</h1>
                </div>
                :
                <div className="slide__title">
              <h1 className="white-text bottom" ref={bottomText}>{category}</h1>
              </div>
              }          
              </div>))      
        }
        <div className="total-images white-text">05</div>
      </div> 
)
```

I am basically mapping out slides of a slideshow for each category (3 images, 1 title per slide). I am using an external WebGL library below (modified for my needs):
https://tympanus.net/Development/MotionRevealSlideshow/

Then, I am trying to apply the CircleType JS library to arc my header texts (top and bottom, but I am just going with the top atm to test things out): 
https://circletype.labwire.ca/

However, when I try to do so, the innerText of the headers return an empty value even though the text is apparent. So after I create a new CircleType instance, the text just disappears and I can't check if it is even curved correctly or not.

I tried a few things to solve this, but no luck. The key things I found out was that,
1. the `innerText` of the top headers inside the `useEffect` is empty, but when I `console.log(innerHTML)` the texts are there.
2. Since (1) is true, I went ahead and made the `innerText` of the headers inside the `useEffect` equal to the `innerHTML`, but when the DOM is rendered fully the text just becomes the full div tag of that particular text. Regardless, the text is not curved.

I thought the `useEffect` of the empty brackets === `componentDidMount`, but if that's the case I have no idea why this is happening.

If anyone could give me some hints or insights on this matter I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi! your code and the problem descriptions are rather complex. It would be great if you could prepare a simple JS-Fiddle od CodePen that demonstrates the problem. From what I noticed: 1) you don't make any use of `ref={bottomText}` but you could if you'd change it to an array. That would perform better in your `useEffect`. 2) There is no need for `[]` at the end of  the `useEffect` since you want to run it every time the component renders, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that `[]` as second argument in `useEffect` is the troublemaker. It causes the `useEffect` to be called only once with default props and stats. Try removing it:

```js
useEffect(() => {
        const slideshow = new Slideshow(document.querySelector('.slideshow'));
        const topText = document.querySelectorAll('.bottom');
        console.log(topText[0].innerText);
        topText.forEach(text=>{
          console.log(text.innerText)
          new CircleType(text).radius(384)
        })
  });
```

[React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) state in a note that

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array (`[]`) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always works.
>
> If you pass an empty array (`[]`), the props and state inside the effect will always have their initial values. While passing [] as the second argument is closer to the familiar `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` mental model, there are usually better solutions to avoid re-running effects too often. Also, don’t forget that React defers running useEffect until after the browser has painted, so doing extra work is less of a problem.